# About n-ary function

Tags: functions

[image]

Hello. When an n-ary function maps n arguments or inputs to a single output . Does that mean that every input  is mapped to this output? Or its just the union of inputs , so that it requires at least one input among them mapped to the output ?

Comment: The def means that e.g. a *binary* function (like the sum: $+$) can be seen - instead of as a function of two arguments: $x+y$, as a function of one single argument: the *pair* $(x,y)$.

Comment: In this case, the *pair* $(x,y)$ is an element of the "product space", i.e. an element of the cartesian product (e.g. $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ for the sum of *naturals*).

Comment: Ah okay now I get it thank you! @Mauro . If your comments were written as an answer I would have chose it

Comment: See [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and [Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a Family of $n$ Inputs $\{I_j \}_{j \in \{ 1, \dots, n\}}$. We define a function of this $n$ Inputs by a function $f$ mapping the $n$-fold cartesian product of all the Inputs to an Output $J$, formally written as:

$f: \times_{j=1}^n I_j \rightarrow J$.

Note that this n-fold cartesian product $\times_{j=1}^n$ is an Operation that forms These $n$ sets $I_j$ to one single new set denoted by $I_{1,\dots,n}$. We can see elements of this set as $n$-tuples $(i_1,\dots,i_n) \in I_{1, \dots, n}$, where $i_1 \in I_1, \dots i_n \in I_n$.

Comment: Thank you! @kryomaxim